# Error in converting daily stock series into monthly ones

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I am a newbie in R and have difficulties converting daily stock series into monthly ones in `xts` class.

I have a stock data about the ticker IOO downloaded into a .csv (Comma delimited) file from Yahoo!Finance looking like this:

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Adjusted Close  Volume

12/31/2012  63      63.95   63      63.95   56.11           87900

1/2/2013    64.94   65.19   64.62   65.08   57.09           77900

1/3/2013    64.94   64.98   64.63   64.68   56.74           36000

1/4/2013    64.70   65.13   64.63   65.12   57.13           49400

1/7/2013    64.83   64.91   64.61   64.88   56.93           102000

1/8/2013    64.65   64.76   64.37   64.58   56.66           31600
```

I have written the following in R in order to read it, convert it to `xts` and convert daily to monthly:

```
library(tseries)

library(xts)

library(PerformanceAnalytics)

IOO <- read.csv(file = “IOO.csv”, header = TRUE, sep = “,”)

IOO <- subset(IOO[, c(1,2,3,4,6)])

colnames(IOO) <- c(“Date”, “Open”, “High”, “Low”, “Close”)

IOO[,“Date”] <- as.Date(IOO[,“Date”], format = “%m / %d / %Y”)

IOO <- as.xts(IOO, order.by = as.Date(rownames(IOO), “%Y-%m-%d”), dateFormat = “POSIXct”, frequency = NULL, .RECLASS = FALSE)

IOO_monthly <- to.monthly(IOO, indexAt=‘yearmon’, drop.time = TRUE, name = NULL)
```

> Error in to.period(x, “months”, indexAt = indexAt, name = name, …) :
>   unsupported type

```
IOO_monthly <- to.period(IOO, period = “months”, indexAt=‘yearmon’, name = NULL)
```

> Error in to.period(IOO, period = “months”, indexAt = “yearmon”, name = NULL) :
>   unsupported type

```
IOO_monthly <- to.period(IOO, period = “months”, indexAt= NULL, name = NULL)
```

> Error in to.period(IOO, period = “months”, indexAt = NULL, name = NULL) :
>   unsupported type

I have tried many other combinations of arguments in `to.period` and `to.monthly`, but it did not work out.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you dput your data?

Comment: @suchait I am not shure how

Comment: Just do `dput(data)`, when you get data in r. And, share it's output. That would be a reproducible example. You should get something starting with `structure`.

Comment: This is not complete. It's not generating any data frame.

Comment: structure(list(Date = structure(c(395L, 32L), .Label = c("1/10/2013", 
"1/10/2014", "1/10/2017", "1/11/2013", "1/11/2016", "1/11/2017"14100L, 21900L, 24700L, 207700L, 14100L, 28600L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj.Close", "Volume"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1260L)) #the first 2 and the last 2 rows look like that, otherwise the data is very long to post it in a comment #that is the data after the code IOO <- read.csv(file = "IOO.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") is performed

Comment: Thank you for your support suchait.                                                            
I received help how to get the same data easier in R:                
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
IOO <- getSymbols("IOO", auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2012-12-31")
to.monthly(IOO)                                                                                     
The error with my codes most probably was that I used old version of R.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it got solved

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question: the problem is that you include the `"Date"` column in the `coredata` of your xts object. xts and zoo objects are simple a matrix with an index attribute (not an index *column*). Since you can't have mixed column types in a matrix, all your data are converted to a single type (character in this case).

```
library(xts)
# Example data
IOO <- read.csv(text="Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted,Close,Volume
12/31/2012,63,63.95,63,63.95,56.11,87900
1/2/2013,64.94,65.19,64.62,65.08,57.09,77900
1/3/2013,64.94,64.98,64.63,64.68,56.74,36000
1/4/2013,64.70,65.13,64.63,65.12,57.13,49400
1/7/2013,64.83,64.91,64.61,64.88,56.93,102000
1/8/2013,64.65,64.76,64.37,64.58,56.66,31600")
# Omit 'Close' and 'Volume' columns
IOO <- IOO[, c(1,2,3,4,6)]
# Rename 'Adjusted' column to 'Close'
colnames(IOO) <- c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close")
# Convert 'Date' column to actual Date class
IOO[, "Date"] <- as.Date(IOO[, "Date"], format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# Create xts object, using 'Date' column as index, and everything else as coredata
IOO <- xts(IOO[,-1], IOO[,1])
# Aggregate to monthly
IOO_monthly <- to.monthly(IOO)
IOO_monthly
#          IOO.Open IOO.High IOO.Low IOO.Close
# Dec 2012    63.00    63.95   63.00     56.11
# Jan 2013    64.94    65.19   64.37     56.66
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua. It is very helpful!